# Benchmark Python programs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. It is my first interpreted language. I used to study Java so far.
So, when Java program runs for the first time, it is execueted slower than for the next times.
The reasi is caching.

```
import time

def procedure():
    time.sleep(2.5)

# measure process time
t0 = time.clock()
procedure()
print (time.clock() - t0), "seconds process time"
```

I tried this for several times. The result is always equal. So, am I right that no cashe interferes and that the benchmark is pretty reliable?

Answer (score 5):

it's OK to do benchmarks like this, the accuracy is good enough for functions which run "long" and pretty constant, like in your example.
But there are some pitfalls: for "quick" functions (like the empty one), you run into precision limits. And for functions which vary in execution time (like net i/o, for example), you have to measure multiple times to find min/max/avg runtime.
And in addition to that, the clock best used differs on platforms: on windows, time.clock() is preferred, on *nix, time.time().

luckily, there is a module which takes care of all that: `timeit`:

```
>>> import time
>>> def procedure():
    pass

>>> def time_this(f):
    t0=time.clock()
    f()
    print((time.clock() - t0), "seconds process time")


>>> time_this(procedure)
1.9555558310457855e-06 seconds process time
>>> time_this(procedure)
1.9555557742023666e-06 seconds process time
>>> time_this(procedure)
1.9555557742023666e-06 seconds process time
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer(procedure).timeit()
0.09460783423588737
>>> timeit.Timer(procedure).repeat()
[0.09791419021132697, 0.09721947901198291, 0.09598943441130814]
```

you might want to look at it's source. Or just use it ;)

As for caching: python code compiles to bytecode when first used. This bytecode is cached by default - but this won't affect your benchmark as long as you don't do `import`s in your function.